# Centering a navbar?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

I’m attaching links of where my Navbar is now, and my intended layout in Illustrator. The problem that I am having is the logo to the left of the nav list is pushing the navbar to the right. I wanted someone’s opinion on the best way to approach this layout from a modern responsive point of view. The main image will eventually be an After Effects or Animate movie but I haven’t added any responsive code yet either. Should I put the header section into a 3 column grid container

Or use Flex like [Nike](https://www.nike.com/)

Using text align center on all Li parent elements, and changing the Z-Index of the header elements.

https://azteramaikoa.000webhostapp.com/

https://azteramaikoa.000webhostapp.com/images/amgridb.png

I need the navbar centered until about 768px wide, at which point the website will have to change because of the main image dimensions.

Comment: https://azteramaikoa.000webhostapp.com/images/amgridc.png

Comment: I have checked the code structure. there are code structural problem according to design. I would like to suggest to you you should use some `CSS Frameworks` and Of Course `CSS Flex` is better option

Comment: What's the structural problem without using Flex. In other words  as is?

Comment: I assumed the logo width is offsetting the navs center position but if I placed another element to the right there could be other issues.